# Asp.net web app shows me as the logged in user on someone elses pc

Tags: c#, asp.net

OK, I really don't know what to search for this, so hopefully someone can help me.

I've just published an asp.net web application, and after much messing about finally got it to load in my browser.

The issue however is that when I got my mate who is sitting next to me to open the site in his browser, the page showed me as the logged in user.

In the default.aspx I run some code that grabs the users windows identity

```
LDAPDetails LDAPUser = new LDAPDetails(WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Token);
```

LDAPDetails then does this.

```
_UserName = windowsId.Name.Substring(windowsId.Name.IndexOf('\\') + 1);
        _DomainName = windowsId.Name.ToString().Remove(windowsId.Name.IndexOf('\\'));

        //Get users information from active directory
        DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher("LDAP://DCHS");
        search.Filter = String.Format("(SAMAccountName={0})", _UserName);
        SearchResult result = search.FindOne();
        if (result != null)
        {
            _FullName = result.Properties["givenName"][0].ToString() + ' ' + result.Properties["sn"][0].ToString();
            _Email = result.Properties["mail"][0].ToString();
            _FirstName = result.Properties["givenName"][0].ToString();
            _SSID = windowsId.User.ToString();
            _errMsg = "";
        }
```

These values are then put into session variables.

It seems that WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Token is still using my details even though its on a machine that i'm not logged into.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Agree with Tim - `WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent()` will be executing on server and will return the windows user under which the server process (worker process in IIS) is running which happens to be your account.

What you need to do is to set up windows/integrated authentication in both IIS and ASP.NET (web.config) and then use `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity` instead of `WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent()`.

Comment: How do I setup windows/integrated authentication in asp.net?

Comment: I think I have it going, however now its just using the credentials of the DefaultAppPool..

Comment: @Matt, see this link to setup windows authentication: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/authenticating-users-with-windows-authentication-cs And are you using `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity`?

Answer (score 3):

The Web application is running on a web server that you are logged into (probably your machine), so the code WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Token is executed on the web server, and of course that will return your credentials.

There are a bunch of different mechanisms for Web app authentication, you need to do some googling.

Comment: ah ok.. The reason I need WindowsIdentity is because I require WindowsIdentity.User.ToString() as part of an authentication process in another system.    Is there  a way to make that possible?

Comment: Yes, see VinayC's answer below. (+1 for Vinay) For what it's worth I personally am not a fan of windows auth, even for Intranet applications. If it's your requirement then so be it. But I would highly recommend that you at least have a good look at other authentication schemes (OAuth is one that comes to mind quickly)

Comment: I'd love to, but we use another application that requres the users SSID. This site i'm building is for managing that system, so it needs to be able to grab that information..

Answer (score 0):

You are likely getting the identity of the process running on the server.  If you are using IIS, this is the account setup in the application pool.  Follow the instructions at this MSDN link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa292114(v=vs.71).aspx for configuring Integrated Windows Authentication on IIS.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `User.Identity.Name` to get the user name?

It uses the [IIdentiy interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.iidentity.aspx)